# Query to get user by email when email is stored in multiple columns

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

My attempt:

```
var user = (await client.Users.Request()
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.OtherMails, x.Identities })
            .Filter($"otherMails/any(id:id eq 'zed@gmail.com') or identities/any(ids:ids/issuerassignedid eq 'zed@gmail.com')")
            .GetAsync());
```

which fails with:

> Complex query on property identities is not supported.

See also [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/query-parameters):

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(displayName,'mary') or 
startswith(givenName,'mary') or startswith(surname,'mary') or startswith(mail,'mary') or 
startswith(userPrincipalName,'mary')
```

**Note that email / OtherEmail fields are not populated.**

[image]

#### Update - revised query fails with same error message.

```
    public async Task<User> GetUserByEmailAddress(string email)
    {
        IGraphServiceUsersCollectionPage users = await client.Users.Request()
            .Select(x => new { x.Id, x.Mail, x.OtherMails, x.Identities })
            .Filter($"mail eq '{email}' or otherMails/any(id:id eq '{email}') or identities/any(ids:ids/issuerassignedid eq '{email}' and ids/signintype eq 'emailAddress')")
            .GetAsync();

        if(users.Any())
            return users[0];
        
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Identities and OtherMails properties of user object support $filter as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties).

Also when filtering on Identities object, you must provide both issuer and issuerAssignedId - refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties) for details.

I am not aware of your requirement but using Identities as filtering for email might not the best choice because ids wont necessarily be emails. If you are fltering for email you can use mail and other mail property - https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=otherMails/any(id:id eq 'mary@xx.live') or mail eq 'mary@xx.live'

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  

> Also when filtering on Identities object, you must provide both issuer and issuerAssignedId 

Good advice, thank you.

> If you are fltering for email you can use mail and other mail property 

I do not believe that is correct.  Those columns are not populated.  Please see screen cap on updated issue.

Comment: Do you get issuerAssignedID and signInType in Identities object? You can query on that signinType field.

Comment: I think if (otherMails OR identities) is too complex for the query parser it is probably going to fail with (otherMails OR (signinType AND issuerAssignedID)).  I'm just guessing.  I will try it.

Comment: See revised query:  https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10672  see also updated post.

Comment: See also [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/10672).

Answer (score 0):

Per [the ticket I raised with Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/161383/query-to-get-user-by-email-when-email-is-stored-in.html?childToView=171436#comment-171436): "the error message is clear. You cannot filter (due not being supported) by identities and some additional property."

So if you need to search by email you have to load your entire user table into memory.